# program that creates one main object and creates a pet for each of them

Tags: swift, oop

I am new to swift coding and I was wondering how you would create a program that creates one main object and creates a pet for each of them. Would you use a string, array or what?

Comment: It is helpful to show what you have done then users can help where you are not understanding.

Comment: I have nothing done that is why I am asking.

Comment: Maybe you should look at a tutorial for swift coding. Here is a good one: http://www.learnswift.tips. And another one here dealing with pets: http://swift.staticred.com/blog/protocols-swift-blueprints-success

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. You want a pet created for each of them.. What is them?  Think about what you want a pet to represent before you think about created strings or arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a swift program that deals with pets. I found it on [here](http://swift.staticred.com/blog/protocols-swift-blueprints-success).

It has a protocol Animal that defines parts to an animal, with int legs, and boolean domesticated.

```
protocol Animal {

    var legs: Int { get set }
    var domesticated: Bool { get }

    func hasFur() -> String
    func countLegs() -> String

}
```

Then the protocol Pet is an Animal.
The variables that need to be defined, leashed, pettable, foodType, and name.

```
protocol Pet : Animal {
    var leashed: Bool { get set }
    var pettable: Bool { get set }
    var foodType: String { get set }
    var name: String { get set }

}
```

Then the class Dog is a Pet. The variables are defined for, legs, domesticated, leashed, pettable, and foodType. 
You still have to worry about name.
You have implementations of the Animal functions hasFur() and countLegs().

```
class Dog: Pet {
    var legs = 4
    let domesticated = true
    var leashed = true
    var pettable = true
    var foodType = "Kibble"
    var name = ""

    func hasFur() -> String {
            return "The dog is furry"
    }

    func countLegs() -> String {
        return "\(name) the dog has \(legs) legs"
    }    
}
```

Here is the "main" where when you run in what ever IDE you are using will run.

```
let Fido = Dog()
Fido.name = "Ralph"
Fido.legs = 3
Fido.countLegs() // Prints “Ralph the dog has 3 legs”

println(Fido.foodType) // Prints “Kibble”
```